# Code to hide only one workbook instead of hiding all currently open workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I usually have multiple workbooks open and on one workbook, I have a VBA code that hides the workbook and shows a UserForm. But when I open that workbook, all of my workbooks that are currently opened will also hide. What code can I use to just hide 1 workbook?

Here are the codes I've tried:

```
ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False

Windows(ThisWorkbook.name).Visible = False

Application.Windows(1).visible = false
```

With `Windows(ThisWorkBook.name).visible = False` works with closing only one workbook, it messes with the workbook and the sheets don't show at all. I can't even close the excel workbook without using the task manager.

Comment: you may be running all workbooks in the same Excel instance, check that...

Comment: and how do i change this?

Answer (score 8):

`ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False` will change the `Visible` property of the **application** running your workbook, i.e. an instance of Excel.EXE ... if this instance is running your other books, too, then as a consequence all these books will disappear from screen.

To hide a single workbook, use

```
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
```

or alternatively, if the workbook you want to hide (e.g. "MyWorkbook") is not the active one

```
Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False
```

Pay attention that hiding a window also moves the pointer to the ActiveSheet, likewise when you reverse this (i.e. `...Visible = True`) the displayed sheet becomes active.

Comment: it says run-time error '1004' : Select method of worksheet class failed. and it doesn't show the userform or the worksheet.

Comment: amazing ... you ain't working on a worksheet object here, but on a window ... have you single-stepped through your code and made sure it's the window/visible statement throwing that error? Other idea: do you have protection on the workbook or the sheet? This could potentially block the hide.

Comment: nope. no protection on the workbook. if it makes a difference, here is my code on this based on the code you provided too:
`Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Main Page").Activate
        ActiveWindow.Visible = False
        Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False
        UserForm1.show
    End Sub`

Comment: when I try to step through it, it says : run-time error 91 : object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: sorry if my answer was misleading ... I clarified on alternative use of `ActiveWindow` vs. window of a named workbook.