# How to speed up macros/hide screen while code is running

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of macros that format a single sheet and import values from hardcoded arrays if a match is found.  The code is well commented.  Macros are called in the order that they are listed.  I would like your opinion on how to speed up the code or hide the sheet from view, so that the user doesn’t see any manipulation on the screen while Macro is running.  Thank you very much.

```
    Sub MacroA()
    '
    ' addcolumn Macro
    '

        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Dim LastRow As Long

        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QC")

        LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       '~~~~~> error checking

                   If Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
                'MsgBox " There are no QC samples on this run"
                Exit Sub
                End If

        Worksheets("QC").Select
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~copy down value from A2

        sht.Range("A2").Value2 = "HD200_QC"
        'copy QC name down
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
     '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete 'removes extra column for interpretation

        Columns("H:H").Select '\\add one column
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        Columns("G:G").Select 'convert formulas to values
        Selection.Copy
        Columns("G:G").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        With sht

        .Range("A1").Value2 = "QC"
        .Range("G1").Value2 = "AAchange"
        .Range("H1").Value2 = "Standard"

         End With
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
Sub deleteIrrelevantColumns() 'delete all columns except for the ones with a certain name.

    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'ActiveSheet.Columns("L").Delete

    For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "QC", "gene", "exon", "cDNA", "AAchange", "%Alt", "Standard"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                'Delete if the cell doesn't contain these
                If InStr(1, _
                   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, _
                   "Matreshkaper", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

                    ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

                End If
        End Select
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub



Sub PopulateStandard()
'PURPOSE: Filter on specific values


Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow, i As Long
Dim GeneCheck As String
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim x
Dim y

'wsQC.Select
Worksheets("QC").Select

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


vArr = Array(Array("HD300_QCL861Q", "5"), _
Array("HD300_QCE746_E749del", "5"), _
Array("HD300_QCL858R", "5"), _
Array("HD300_QCT790M", "5"), _
Array("HD300_QCG719S", "5"), _
Array("HD200_QCV600E", "10.5"), _
Array("HD200_QCD816V", "10"), _
Array("HD200_QCE746_E749del", "2"), _
Array("HD200_QCL858R", "3"), _
Array("HD200_QCT790M", "1"), _
Array("HD200_QCG719S", "24.5"), _
Array("HD200_QCG13D", "15"), _
Array("HD200_QCG12D", "6"), _
Array("HD200_QCQ61K", "12.5"), _
Array("HD200_QCH1047R", "17.5"), _
Array("HD200_QCE545K", "9"))



For i = 2 To LastRow

GeneCheck = Right(Cells(i, 1).Value, 8) & Cells(i, 5).Value

'//Tell VBA to ignore an error and continue (ie if it can't find the value)
        On Error Resume Next

'//Assign the result of your calculation to a variable that VBA can query

    x = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(GeneCheck, vArr, 2, False)



     '//if Vlookup finds the value, then paste it into the required column
        If Err = 0 Then

    Cells(i, 6).Value = x
            Else

            End If

            '//resets to normal error handling
            On Error GoTo 0
Next


Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub MissingValues()

Dim zArr As Variant
Dim yArr As Variant

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QC")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

yArr = Array(Array("EGFR", "", "", "L861Q", "5"), _
       Array("EGFR", "", "", "KELRE745delinsK", "5"), _
       Array("EGFR", "", "", "L858R", "5"), _
       Array("EGFR", "", "", "T790M", "5"), _
       Array("EGFR", "", "", "G719S", "5"))

zArr = Array(Array("BRAF", "", "", "V600E", "10.5"), _
        Array("KIT", "", "", "D816V", "10"), _
        Array("EGFR", "", "", "KELRE745delinsK", "2"), _
        Array("EGFR", "", "", "L858R", "3"), _
        Array("EGFR", "", "", "T790M", "1"), _
        Array("EGFR", "", "", "G719S", "24.5"), _
        Array("KRAS", "", "", "G13D", "15"), _
        Array("KRAS", "", "", "G12D", "6"), _
        Array("NRAS", "", "", "Q61K", "12.5"), _
        Array("PIK3CA", "", "", "H1047R", "17.5"), _
        Array("PIK3CA", "", "", "E545K", "9"))

'Ctrl + Shift + End
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value, "HD200") > 0 Then


    Sheets("QC").Select
        Worksheets("QC").Range("B" & LastRow + 2 & ":F" & LastRow + 12).Value = Application.Index(zArr, 0)

ElseIf InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value, "HD300") > 0 Then


    Sheets("QC").Select
        Worksheets("QC").Range("B" & LastRow + 2 & ":F" & LastRow + 6).Value = Application.Index(yArr, 0)

End If

LastRow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'MsgBox (LastRow2)

Columns("B:G").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$" & LastRow2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 5, 6), _
        Header:=xlYes
    Range("A1").Select


With Worksheets("QC")
        'lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = "Removed Low Alts."
End With

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Columns("A:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select


    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QC").Sort.SortFields.clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F2:F" & LastRow), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QC").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:G" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With



    ' Adds a grid around the data
LastRow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:G" & LastRow2).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    '~~~~> add yellow color
    Range("F2:G" & LastRow2).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12514808
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    '~~~~> make font red
     Range("F2:F" & LastRow2).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16777024
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With


    Range("A1").Select

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub Filter()


'PURPOSE: Filter on specific values


Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow, i As Long
Dim GeneCheck As String
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim x
Dim y
Dim FilterField As Variant
'wsQC.Select
Worksheets("QC").Select

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AC" & LastRow)
FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("AAchange", rng.Rows(1), 0)

'Turn on filter if not already turned on
 'If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then rng.AutoFilter

      If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value, "HD200") > 0 Then
     rng.AutoFilter
'Filter Specific Countries
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "V600E", "KELRE745delinsK", "T790M", "G719S", "D816V", "G13D", "G12D", "Q61K", "H1047R", "L858R", "E545K"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

     Else 'If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value, "HD300") > 0 Then

     rng.AutoFilter
      rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=Array( _
      "L861Q", "KELRE745delinsK", "L858R", "T790M", "G719S"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

     End If

'End If

 '~~~> format top row.
 Range("A1").Select 'format top row
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 90
        .Gradient.ColorStops.clear
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .Color = 11298378
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .Color = 5384228
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With



Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: At the beginning of the macro add 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False'. At the end of the macro add 'Application.ScreenUpdating = True'. Note that if the macro crashes before it gets to the end, your screen will be frozen without additional manual intervention. If you want to use this method, you must add proper error handling to ensure that the screen updating is turned on.

Comment: Sorry, but I already have 'Application.ScreenUpdating = False'. Is there anything else that can be done? Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602997/code-to-hide-only-one-workbook-instead-of-hiding-all-currently-open-workbooks

Comment: If you already do that [I did not read the code, I admit, as there is far too much there to go through easily], the user should not experience any changes occurring during the running of the macro. Are you sure that command is working as expected? Also - you must add error handling so that if an error pops up, the code jumps to a section which states that screen updating is back on.

Answer (score 0):

Just this bit of code to add borders could speed things up.

```
LastRow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:G" & LastRow2).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .colorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
```

Can be replaced with this. Edit your code to remove the selects.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QC")
Dim rng As Range

LastRow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sht.Range("A2:G" & LastRow2)

With rng.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
```